# Can I add a button on tables that export them to .csv?

Tags: tables, interaction

Is there any package that allow us to create a button to export a table as .csv?

Is this kind of interactivity of easy coping tables possible with latex?

It would be a tool for someone that take the pdf and want to open the data on Excel easily.

As an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\hline 
7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opnion the connectivity is interaction. What do you propose @Mico?

Comment: please closers at only 55 min

Comment: please give more informations about the table? are you creating it using latex and you want to export it from pdf?

Comment: I am not sure, since i don't know java scripting, but i think this could be possible using [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) form.

Comment: A reader most likely doesn't care how the pdf was produced and hence doesn't need to know anything about latex. And the reader also doesn't export anything from latex.

Comment: @Johannes_B can you please explain a bit what you mean? I think the question is about export from the pdf.

Comment: @touhami i was referring to a comment by the OP which confused me.

Comment: @Johannes_B was right. I deleted this comment.

Comment: Vitor, although the idea of attaching a file is interesting, I'd be *very* reticent on doing so because of the plethora of PDF viewers out there which do not have this bit of the PDF spec covered. Granted, it's not your problem that other people don't use a "better PDF viewer", but it might cause embarrassment and frustration in the long run. I'd simply put the corresponding `.csv` file somewhere in the Internet and then `hyperref` it from my document. Not exactly what you want, but it ensures everybody who has access to your document will be able to obtain the data regardless of the viewer.

Comment: In Linux old glories as  `xpdf` and `gv` still do not support attached files, but there are no problem with most popular `atril, evince, okular, qpdfview ...` and I guess that  it is also true for `acroread` (that mean the viewer of most  Window users and some Linux users too) .   The main problem could be the PDF viewers of web browsers, that will be used by many people at first instance when the PDF is an email attach or a web link.

Comment: @Mico And I have deleted mine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [image: mwe]

(obviously, this does not work in the PNG image)

I do not know such functionality (export a  LaTeX table in a PDF to a CSV file), but may be you can use the **[attachfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile)** package so that the PDF files can con­tain attached these CSV files. The package allows ar­bi­trary LaTeX code for the file icon (­a graph­ic or a table, for example).

Make the tables previously in CSV format do not mean double work, since LaTeX can  import these CSV data to make this PDF. See CTAN's topics 
[data-import](https://www.ctan.org/topic/data-import) and 
[csv-sup­port](https://www.ctan.org/topic/csv-support).
With `filecontents` you can use the same LaTeX file to make the CSV files. Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
1,2,3 
4,5,6
7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}
\parindent0pt\parskip1em\fboxsep1em
\begin{document}

Click  on \noattachfile{} icon\\
to export to CSV:

\fbox{\attachfile{table.csv}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline 
4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline 
7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline 
\end{tabular}} 

\end{document}
```

Another possibility to convert CSV in tabular data is read (or make) the CSV files with R and export to LaTeX with [xtable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html), for example (See CRAN's Task View [Reproducible Research](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html) for another options).

Is is worth to note that R code chunks could be executed inside LaTeX documents (but with .Rnw extension) and replaced with the R ouput in the PDF with the help of `Sweave` or `knitr` (see the above link). There are many examples of use  `Sweave` and  `knitr` in this site. Example:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\parindent0pt\parskip1em\fboxsep1em
<<echo=F>>=
table <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),ncol=3) 
write.csv(table, file = "table.csv")
@
\begin{document}
Click  on \noattachfile{} icon\\
to export to CSV:

\fbox{\attachfile{table.csv}
<<results="asis",echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(table,digits=0), floating=F, 
      include.rownames=F, include.colnames=F)
@
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that attach a file is a possible way to solve the problem

Comment: I AM CLICKING THE IMAGE GIMME THE FILE THINGY! (`+1` by the way) `:)` `♥♥♥♥♥`

Comment: @PauloCereda He knew that some duck would fall into that puddle !  XD

Comment: @Fran ducks are very naïve creatures. `:)`

Comment: It is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is the current best solution.