# How to get the specific line on LATEX to show properly for copy and pasting?

Tags: listings, overleaf

How can I show this line properly for my Latex document? I am trying to put in code statements but when I try to copy from LATEX and post in the terminal, it does not paste the whole line.

The code for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry} % Adjust margins if needed
\usepackage{listings} % For code snippets
\usepackage{xcolor} % For syntax highlighting
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\lstset{
    language=python,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green!60!black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    frame=single,
    captionpos=b,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, % If you need to include LaTeX code within listings
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{OpenCV}
This section will cover the basic steps for opencv installation. Please follow the necessary steps:
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={OpenCV 4.5.3}]
(*@sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev@*)
(*@sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev@*)
(*@sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config@*)
(*@sudo apt-get update@*)
(*@sudo apt-get install cmake@*)
# This line does not show properly:
(*@sudo cmake -D WITH\_GSTREAMER=ON -D OPENCV\_GENERATE\_PKGCONFIG=ON -D WITH\_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH\_GTK=ON  /media/nvidia/ssd120G/opencv-4.5.3@*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I am by no means an advanced latex user. Thank you for your help.

[image: LATEX_SS]

Comment: well there is a line break, you need to remove that. But you should not rely on copy & paste from a PDF for code blocks,  it can work, but it can also loose spaces or insert as in your case line breaks.

Comment: Suggerence: attach as plain text files the code to copy https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315361/11604